# Make looping left-right transition on overlay image with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am trying to have an output video using ffmpeg with:

- a base video "video.mp4"
- a static overlay image "staticimage.png"
- an overlay image that makes looping transition left-right "movingimage.png"

Here is what I could make so far:

```
ffmpeg -i "video.mp4" -i "movingimage.png" -i "staticimage.png" -filter_complex "[0]overlay=x='if(gte(t,0), -w+(t)*100, 3)':y=0[v];[v][2]overlay=0:0[vt];[1][vt]overlay=0:0" -c:a copy -vcodec libx264 -preset superfast -f flv "output.flv"
```

This command is successful so far. However the moving image only does one transition. Is there a way to make it loop and start all over again for the initial position (left)?

Your help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For looping, you want a periodic function, usually mod.

In this case,

```
x='-w+100*mod(t,(W+w)/100)'
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you very much.